# Converting str object to int in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am currently making a scoreboard for a yatzhee game in python where I'm using a dictionary to associate where a player's points will be inserted into a table.
The dictionary looks like this from the start:

```
 self.lista={"aces":'',"twos":'',"threes":'',"fours":''}
```

When I associate for example the number 25 with "aces" I want it to be interpreted as an integer, so when the next time I add points to "aces" it adds them up with 25. Is there a way to this?

Comment: yes. the dict does not care what type you insert as value, you can put an int.

Answer (score 3):

```
self.lista = {"aces":'',"twos":'',"threes":'',"fours":''}
self.lista['aces'] = 25 --> # 25
self.lista['aces'] += 25 --> # 50
```

OT (for the future reference):
You can initialize your dict with keys in this way:

```
keys = ['aces', 'twos', 'threes', 'fours']
self.lista = dict.fromkeys(keys)
print self.lista --> # {'aces': None, 'fours': None, 'twos': None, 'threes': None}
```

Comment: I don't see any connection.

Comment: that means you dont have to create a new dict to call fromkeys - `dict.fromkeys` is better than `{}.fromkeys`

Comment: Let it be guys, now it's faster :)